# Color Picker for iOS

Tags: ios, ios5

I am totally new to iPhone, can anyone suggest me color picker with automatic reference counting ? I need to create simple project with choosing color and I tried to add 
https://github.com/hayashi311/Color-Picker-for-iOS but I got errors for synthesize keyword. Is there any already color picker that is part of framework ?

Comment: It would help if you posted the exact errors you received and their corresponding file names and line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable ARC for select files like the color picker you mentioned using the compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc`. More here: [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)